# jQuery - Why are my string values being truncated?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html

It has been several years since I've worked with jQuery, I am sure I am missing something obvious, but I cannot figure out what is going on with my values.

I have several text boxes, and a multi select. The text boxes gather: Weight, Moisture % and Number of Filled Squares.

The multi select has building specific information, in regards to square footage per square. Some of the squares are even, for example 22 square feet. The others, carry two decimal places, IE 21.88.

When doing my calculations with the strings, my numbers come back strange. After  logging my variables to the console in order of execution, I can see that my values are doing one of two things. They're either being rounded up, or being truncated to remove the decimals.

Here is the code I am working with:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#btn_calculate').click(function(){
        // This is the 'Truck Weight' text box
        var TruckWeight = parseInt($('#input-number-weight').val(), 10);
        console.log('Truck Weight :' + TruckWeight + ' .');

        // This is the moisture percentage text box
        var Moisture = parseInt($('#input-number-moisture').val(), 10);    
        console.log('Moisture:'+ Moisture +' .');

        //This is the number of squares filled out, squares text box
        var Squares = parseFloat($('#input-number-squares').val());

        //I am not sure if this is necessary. 
        var ParseSquares = parseFloat(Squares);
        console.log('ParseSquares: '+ ParseSquares +' .');

        // Trying to prohibit the function from rounding the strings down/up 
        var Double = parseInt($('#select-doubles option:selected').val(), 10);
        console.log('Double: '+ Double +' .');

        <!-- testing percentages -->
        var number = TruckWeight;
        console.log('Number : '+number+' .');
        var percentX = (100 - Moisture) - 1;
        console.log('PercentX : '+percentX+' .');
        var result;
        console.log('Result :'+ result +' .');

        function percentCalculation(a, b){
          var c = (parseFloat(a)*parseFloat(b))/100;
          return Math.round(c);
        }

        <!-- take the moisture percent out of 100 and multiply it by the weight of the truck -->
        result = percentCalculation(number, percentX); //calculate percentX% of number      
        console.log(result);
        console.log('Result :'+ result +' .');  



        var dry_matter = TruckWeight * result;
        console.log('Dry Matter: '+ dry_matter +' .');
        var squares_square_feet = (Squares * Double);
        console.log('Squares Square Feet : ' + squares_square_feet +' .');
        var dry_weight = dry_matter/squares_square_feet;
        console.log('Dry Weight: ' + dry_weight + ' .');

    });
});
```

The breakdown is for this particular item:

```
var Double = parseInt($('#select-doubles option:selected').val(), 10);
```

## select-doubles is a select box, which has each value set at the particular square footage for the selected room. For example option 1 will have a value of 21.9 square feet. Option 2 will have 21.84 square feet.

The issue I am having is that this string is truncating the decimal points, and this is messing my math up.

I am sure I am probably doing this wrong, or in a manner which is less than ideal. I love criticism, and helpful guidance. If anyone has any ideas which might alleviate the issue I am having with decimals, I'm all for it.

What I had tried, is this block:

```
    //I am not sure if this is necessary. 
    var ParseSquares = parseFloat(Squares);
    console.log('ParseSquares: '+ ParseSquares +' .');

    // Trying to prohibit the function from rounding the strings down/up 
    var Double = parseInt($('#select-doubles option:selected').val(), 10);
    console.log('Double: '+ Double +' .');
```

Some googling lead me to try these methods, but the result is the same.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can you provide a working fiddle?

Comment: As Nathan suggested, `parseInt()` will definately swallow your decimals.

Comment: No need for a fiddle, switching over to parseFloat works! I had tried parseFloat, but stupidly not on the appropriate strings. All is working as expected, thanks to @Nathan P.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, `parseInt` parses integer values, as it says. You should use `parseFloat` to parse some decimal values.

```
// Say that $('#select-doubles option:selected').val() is equal to 21.9
var Double = parseInt($('#select-doubles option:selected').val(), 10);
// Double is now equal to 21, as you parsed it to an integer value.
// But if you use parseFloat instead :
Double = parseFloat($('#select-doubles option:selected').val());
// Double is now equal to 21.9
```

Comment: Very helpful Nathan, thank you kindly. Everything is functioning as expected now. Time do do some more reading.